# Wolfram alpha plot a sum with 2 unknowns

Tags: finance, wolfram-alpha

Let's say I bought a property for 80,000 that I will be renting for 1,200 a year with a 5% yearly increase from the previous year.

Let's call y the number of years required to get my money back. Of course we're ignoring all other expenses and missed payments.

So far everything is simple. 80000=sum(1200*1.05^y) and we solve for y.

[Solve for y with Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=80000%3Dsum%281200*1.05%5Ey%29%20y%20from%200%20to%20y)

Let's assume now that the increase rate is unknown and call it t. What I'm trying to do is to plot the graph that gives y in terms of t. I want to be able to read information like. y=20 when t=2, y=12 when t=5... (Those examples must be wrong).

I tried this on Wolfram Alpha but still can't get the graph that I'm looking for. I'm very novice with the tool.

[My attempt with y and t both unknowns](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%2080000%3Dsum%281200*%28%28t%2B100%29%2F100%29%5Ey%29%20y%20from%200%20to%20y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$80000=1200\sum_{x=0}^y (1+t)^x$$

It exists a close formula for the sum, because it is the partial sum of a geometric series.

$$80000=1200\cdot \frac{(1+t)^{y+1}-1}{t}$$

$\frac{200}3t=(1+t)^{y+1}-1$

$\frac{200}3t+1=(1+t)^{y+1}$

Taking logs on both sides

$\ln\left(\frac{200}3t+1 \right)=(y+1)\cdot \ln(1+t)$

$$y(t)=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{200}3t+1 \right)}{\ln(1+t)}-1$$

For $t=0.05$ you get y=[29.0539](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln(%5Cfrac%7B200%7D3*0.05%2B1+)%7D%7B%5Cln(1%2B0.05)%7D-1)

The plot on [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B200%7D3t%2B1%20%5Cright)%7D%7B%5Cln(1%2Bt)%7D-1,%20t%20from%200%20to%200.3) looks like [image: plot]

Comment: Just in the first equation, 1200 instead of 12000. Thanks!

Comment: @ammoun Yes, thanks. You have good eyes. You´re welcome.